# How to add this Bootstrap calendar into my Laravel project?

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel

Here is the bootstrap calendar repository I am trying to implement into my Laravel project: https://github.com/Paul-DS/bootstrap-year-calendar/

Here's what I have tried but not showing:

Added the repository files into `public` folder, linked the `bootstrap-year-calendar.js` and `bootstrap-year-calendar.css` file in the page

```
<div class="calendar"></div>

<script>
     $('.calendar').calendar()
</script>
```

But it is not showing the calendar. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Did you have some error ?
and did you compile ? 
When i want to include JS lib, i need to compile and add lib in webpack.mix

Comment: Any errors in your console? Did you also load Bootstrap and jQuery? And your script preferably _after_ you load jQuery?

Comment: No error in the console.

Comment: I also loaded bootstrap and JQuery.

Comment: Could you show us how you included the js and css files?

Comment: please put your script and the respective css in public folder and then load 
<script src="{{asset('js/your_js_file.js')}}"></script> then after loading your above code